# Граббер фото viber, whatsapp, telegram на компьютере

Tags: android, python, windows, telegram, синхронизация

Есть список телефонов и имен в контактах на телефоне. При нажатии на контакт бывает что этот человек есть в viber, whatsapp или telegram. При нажатии написать сообщение можно увидеть фото человека.

Какими способами можно вытянуть фото из меседжеров и вставить (экспортировать) в контакты в телефоны автоматически?

Может можно это сделать это через python? Дайте направления пожалуйста

Comment: Вот [хабро-статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/262053/) для примера

Comment: 99% вероятности, что все эти проги для хранения используют `sqlite`.